# WP8 Network Status - App Crash When it has No Network

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have i am currently developing a WP8 application, i have been struggling with a problem for about a month now,

It a music player it plays from remote urls but if there is no internet connect i.e 3g or wifi and you had a song in the play list the app crashes unexpectedly

i was wondering if it is possible to set it so when the app starts it checks the network status and if there is no internet connection it bring up a notification saying there is no connection then closes the app? if it is possible is there somebody who can point me in the right direction as to where to begin,

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it C or C# you are coding in? Btw: And what happens if the network connections goes down while the app is already running?

Comment: C#, as far as i know it freezes until you select a song then crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use WebClient to retrieve Data from websites, use ping or check the networkinterface.

**WebClient**

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new System.Uri("http://google.com"));
```

Check for Error:

```
    private void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("An Error has occured. Maybe the website you are trying to reach is offline or you have no internetconnection");
            });
        }
    }
```

**Ping**

```
public bool CheckInternetConnection()
{
    bool success = false;
    using (Ping ping = new Ping())
    {
        try
        {
            if (ping.Send("google.com", 2000).Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                success= true;
            }
        }
        catch (PingException)
        {
            success = false;
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

**Check networkinterface**

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;

private void CheckInetConnection()
{
    if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() == true)
    {
        //Internet avalaible
    }
    else
    {
       //No connection available
    }
}
```

You can close an app with C# using following code:

```
Application.Current.Exit();
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say thank you i got the same answer from another post but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn about **Exceptions and how to handle them** - at least it is how I would do it and expect it to be handled with [More on this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx)

Unless of course you already know that and the app is crashing with no apparent reason. (Just a rookie's advice :) Maybe I'm wrong, but you didn't give any clues so I don't have any info about your skill level or what you know)

Comment: Im A Noivce when it comes to wp8, im learning as i am going. all i can tell is the entire app runs smoothly until there is no connection then you select a song and then it crashes. is there not a simple way to sort it. for example check network status before it plays a song

Comment: @user2529139: Your proposed approach is an unsatisfying workaround, at least in the long run. Network applications you be capable to react to network outages at **any** time (they access the network typically doing reads or writes), as the network could go down at **any** time.